# how to set ACL in loopback correctly

Tags: loopbackjs

I am having problem with acl in loopback.
I am able to create Role and RoleMapping collection in the database correctely.
The problem is when admin try to create a new product it says unauthorized. Can some one guide what I am doing wrong or guide me correct way of doing it.

project.json

```
{
  "name": "product",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {

    "admin": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "admin",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

admin.json

```
    {
  "name": "admin",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "products": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "product",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

admin.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Admin) {

Admin.afterRemote('create', function(context, user, next) {

        Admin.app.models.Role.upsertWithWhere({
            name: 'admin'
          },{name:'admin'}, function(err, role) {
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log('Created role:', role);

            role.principals.create({
              principalType: Admin.app.models.RoleMapping.ROLE,
              principalId: user.id
            }, function(err, principal) {
              if (err) throw err;

              console.log('Created principal:', principal);

            });
           });


           next();
    });


};
```

Answer (score 0):

LoopBack documentation is very clear about ACL management, from http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html#static-roles

```js
Role.create({
  name: 'admin'
}, function(err, role) {
  if (err) cb(err);

  role.principals.create({
    principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
    principalId: <USER_ID>
  }, function(err, principal) {
    cb(err);
  });
});
```

The example for the static role `admin` takes memory as your primary storage and the code needs to be executed for each boot. If you're using a persistent database you need to create the admin role only once, then you can assign the admin role to your users.

`project.json` ACL is already fine, these are the steps you need to take:

1. Remove `admin.json` and `admin.js` because you don't need that entity to handle resources authorization.
2. Create a script that creates the Role `admin` if it doesn't exist yet.
3. Create a script that takes a user id as parameter and gives the Role `admin` to the given User.